# Arc length of circle overlaping with ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In the case of a arbitrary circle overlapping with an ellipse in the origin.
I don't think there is a closed expression to find the intersection points.
However, I was wondering, is there a (well?) known closed expression (this may be a series expansion) to describe the arc length (red) of the part of the circle overlapping with an ellipse?

Let us define the ellipse as

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

and the circle

$${(x-x_0)^2}+ {(y-y_0)^2} = r^2$$

I think the polar coordinates will be perhaps more helpful for this problem :

$$\begin{array}{lcl}x&=&r\cos(t) + x_0\\y&=&r\sin(t) + y_0\end{array}$$

[image]

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the centre of the circle and its radius?

Comment: I have added the parameterizations with all parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate $y$, and get a single equation in $x$, which is is a degree-4 polynomial.
Expand the second equation, and use the first equation to eliminate the $y^2$ term.  So you have $y$ equal to a quadratic in $x$.  Square both sides, and eliminate $y^2$ again.

Comment: Yes. But is your suggestion then that I for example use a perturbation series to describe the solutions of this polynomial? If that is what you are suggesting I can accept this answer

Comment: I thought one equation in one variable was simpler than two in two.  I'm not sure about perturbation series, unless you are talking about Newton's method.